# What exactly is the issue. An error with the else if logic? Expected primary expression before else

Tags: c++, expression

Everything other than the else part is giving me the strange ( Expected primary expression before else ) error. IM thinking it may have something to do with the limitations of the logic . But I cant seem to wrap my head around the error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int numberRegistered = 0;
const double feePerOneThroughFour = 0.0;
const double feePerFiveThroughTen = 0.0;
const double feeElevenOrMore = 0.0;

double moneyOwed = 0.0;

cout << " Enter in the Number of Registered people";
cin >> numberRegistered;

if (numberRegistered <= 0 );
{
cout << " You have entered in either the number 0 or a negative number" ;
}
        else 
             if  (numberRegistered == 1 ) ||  (numberRegistered == 2) || (numberRegistered == 3 ) ||  (numberRegistered == 4) 
             moneyOwed = numberRegistered * feePerOneThroughFour;
             cout << " Money Owed : $ " ;
             cin >> moneyOwed ;

            else if  (numberRegistered == 5 ) ||  (numberRegistered == 6) || (numberRegistered == 7 ) ||  (numberRegistered == 8) || (numberRegistered == 9)  || (numberRegistered == 10)
            moneyOwed = numberRegistered * feePerFiveThroughTen;
            cout << " Money Owed : $ " ;
            cin >> moneyOwed ;

                    else if  (numberRegistered >= 11) 
                    moneyOwed = numberRegistered * feeElevenOrMore;
                    cout << " Money Owed : $ " ;
                    cin >> moneyOwed ;

system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Semicolon at the end of your if statement.

Comment: C++ is not python, whitespace isn't significant. You need braces around blocks.

Comment: This isn't Python. Your mixing them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a semicolon at the end of your `if`:

```
if();
   ^^^^
```

---

Also, you are missing braces `{ }` after conditional statements.

---

```
if  (numberRegistered == 1 ) ||  (numberRegistered == 2) || (numberRegistered == 3 ) ||  (numberRegistered == 4)
```

You are missing the brackets:

```
if( (numberRegistered == 1 ) ||  (numberRegistered == 2) || (numberRegistered == 3 ) ||  (numberRegistered == 4) )
```

Comment: Also the other if statements have too few brackets. And, although not syntactically invalid, he probably wants more braces around what's under the if statements.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Yup thats true.

Comment: I know your answer is a work in progress, I hope it addresses the `if  (numberRegistered == 1 ) ||...` soon.

Comment: I added back in the brackets and took away the first if statements semi colon. Still ending up with a new error that expects an primary expression before the || token and it wants a ; before the " { " brackets

Comment: @RickTheSlick: Updated the answer. Btw you do really need a good book. You cannot compile programs on a programming forum.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean by brackets . I call these brackets--- >  { { } }    . in this case you are calling   (    )  brackets. I added them in as you have there and  it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use brackets for each if and else

Answer (score 0):

if (numberRegistered <= 0 ); you have a extra semicolon and try to use { } when you have nested if /else to avoid logic problems

Comment: It was that AND the use of double parentheses around the else if statement .

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the semi-colon at the end of an `if`-statement is a common mistake. You meant:

```
if (numberRegistered <= 0)
{
    // [...]
}
```

The next `else if` block has another couple of issues. First, you need to wrap the entire expression in parentheses (which is the compiler error you're seeing), and then wrap the block in braces:

```
else if ((numberRegistered == 1) || (numberRegistered == 2) || (numberRegistered == 3 ) || (numberRegistered == 4))
{
    moneyOwed = numberRegistered * feePerOneThroughFour;
    cout << " Money Owed : $ " ;
    cin >> moneyOwed ;
}
```

You could shorten this to improve readability:

```
else if ((numberRegistered >= 1 ) && (numberRegistered <= 4))
{
    moneyOwed = numberRegistered * feePerOneThroughFour;
    cout << " Money Owed : $ " ;
    cin >> moneyOwed ;
}
```

The rest of your `else if` blocks have the same issues.

Comment: Dang. This would have helped me as I JUST solved it. Thanks though.